# Residual Neural Network: Concatenation or Element Addition?

Tags: neural-network, resnet, deep-residual-networks

With the residual block in residual neural networks, is the addition at the end of the block true element addition or is it concatenation?

For example, would `addition([1, 2], [3, 4])` produce `[1, 2, 3, 4]` or `[4, 6]` ?

Comment: It is element-wise addition.

Answer (score 5):

It would result in [4, 6], and you can find out more in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

> The operation F + x is performed by a shortcut
> connection and **element-wise addition**

It is from the popular ResNet paper by Microsoft Research. Therefore it is element-wise addition, hence [4, 6]