# Implementing residual block

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, deep-residual-networks

In the traditional residual block, is the "addition" of layer N to the output of layer N+2 (prior to non-linearity) element-wise addition or concatenation?

The literature indicates something like this:

```
X1 = X
X2 = relu(conv(X1))
X3 = conv(X2)
X4 = relu(conv(X3 + X1))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46902386/712995

Answer (score 1):

It has to be element-wise, with concatenation you don't get a residual function. One has also to be aware about using the proper padding mode so convolutions produce outputs with the same spatial dimensions as the block input.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Since the convolutions must retain dimensions, does the input ever change size as it flows through the net?

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira It does through some blocks between the residual ones. Read the ResNet paper for more information about their architecture.